# ServiceStack client routes for ExpressJs conditional routes

Tags: c#, express, routes, servicestack

ExpressJs allows you to match conditional (aka dynamic or ambiguous) route matching. A route like `GET '/people(/sex/:sexFilter)?(/age-over/:ageOverFilter)?'`

would match the following examples:
`/people`
`/people/sex/female`
`/people/sex/female/age-over/30`
and (most importantly) `/people/age-over/30`

I'm wondering if there's a way to configure a ServiceStack (for a C# Xamarin app) client that would generate the following routes if the request dto object properties were left `null` like:

```
HttpService.Instance.Get<Person[]>(new SearchPeopleRoute() { sexFilter = "female" });
// Generates /people/sex/female

HttpService.Instance.Get<Person[]>(new SearchPeopleRoute() { ageOverFilter = 30 });
// Generates /people/age-over/30
```

The solution would need to be scalable to many search filters, so having a `[Route(...)]` attribute for each permutation of the filters wouldn't be maintainable.

I don't know if there's a way to generate the route at runtime before the call, but that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ServiceStack you would need to list the different routes you want the Service to be able to be called with, e.g:

```
[Route("/people")]
[Route("/people/sex/{Sex}")]
[Route("/people/sex/{Sex}/age-over/{AgeOver}")]
public class SearchPeopleRoute
{
     public string Sex { get; set; }
     public int? AgeOver { get; set; }
}
```

The C#/.NET Service Clients then chooses the most appropriate route based on what the Request DTO is populated with.

For queries in ServiceStack you're encouraged to use the `?queryString` to apply any filters which is more appropriate for designing HTTP APIs as the `/path/info` is used to identify the resource whilst the `?queryString` is used to apply modifiers to that resource request.

This convention is [embraced in AutoQuery](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) which lets you define a Request DTO like:

```
[Route("/people")]
public class SearchPeople : QueryDb<Person> {}
```

And without needing to implement the implementation will let you query [implicit conventions](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#implicit-conventions) for any fields on the `Person` table, where the above AutoQuery Request DTO automatically supports the below queries:

```
/people
/people?sex=female
/people?ageOver=30
/people?sex=female&ageOver=30
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I guess, if that's the only solution with ServiceStack, I'll have to change the package I use. It's too bad they don't allow you to create your routes at runtime. I find it's a bit rigid (maybe intentionally) on their part.

There's been a lot of debates on how REST routes should be formed, and when we did the server-side, that's the way we chose. You're probably right to separate the way identifiers and filters are represented in the URL. When you think about it, they are 2 different concepts.